# Git - Clone subdirectory in server root

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket, git-clone

I've a project structure like this in a git repo:

```
/Code
    /admin
    /api
/DB
/Docs-Files
/UI-UX
```

I want to clone `/admin` and `/api` onto my server `www` directory and keep it in sync with git, so that the structure on server becomes:

```
/www
    /admin
    /api
```

So is it possible to clone like that? I checked out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository) and was able to clone `/Code/admin` and `/Code/api` under `www`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of depending directly on GIT, you could use symlinks. I am assuming that you already have the sparse-checkout done correctly, so could just do:

#### On *nix

```bash
ln -s /Code/admin /www/admin
ln -s /Code/api /www/api
```

#### On Windows

(obviously, looking at the paths, I don't think you are using Windows, but for the sake of completeness)

```bash
mklink /J /www/admin /Code/admin
mklink /J /www/api /Code/api
```

(Note that the args in `ln` and `mklink` are in the opposite order. In the former the `source` is the first arg whereas it is the second one in the latter.)

Then you would just do you Git-y work in the original /Code directory.

Comment: Will the API function with symlinks? I mean will the paremeters be passed without any issue?

Comment: What do you mean by _the API_ ?

Comment: Do i need to `cd` into `www` directory and then run the commands?

Comment: You would need to go into `/www/admin` or `/www/api` directories since they are the links to the directories under version control.

Comment: I meant do i need to `cd` to some directory first(like Code) and then run the two commands you mentioned. Or should i just open up the terminal and run the two commands?

Comment: Open terminal and run the commands. Notice that the commands I have posted have absolute paths so the location where you run from does not matter.

Comment: Thanks. In my case the path was `/var/www/Code/` so I'd to adjust accordingly.